# focus close button in the popup when it is popped up

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a **div** as

```
     <div id="modal"   tabindex="-1" ng-show="booleanvariable" ></div>
```

which I **show** when **ng-show** is true, however I have **close** button under the div which needs to be focussed when the div is showed.We can do that using

```
      $timeout(function() 
         {
                $('.close').focus();
         }, 5000);
```

Is there any show event  like **onShow**, so that I will place my above code in the onShow event.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: Not totally clear what you want to have happen here.

Comment: @jonmrich I mean, I have a popup which is opening fine, however I want to focus the close button in the pop when the popup opens,i will show in detail in the question, thanks jonmrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could watch your model bound to ng-show and trigger it when the right state has been reached.

```
$scope.$watch('isShown', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $log.log('Changed!');
        if(newValue === true) {
            angular.element('.close').focus();
            // or you might have to wrap it with $timeout
            $timeout(function(){
                angular.element('.close').focus();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Brand, thanks for your reply, do you say like isShown event gets triggered when ng-show is true?, why because I have lot of ng-shows, however i want this behaviour when a particular ng-show event

Comment: isShown is not an event, it's meant to be the scope property that's bound to the ng-show directive, check out the $watch function on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: ya, I tried that,somehow it seems my dom is not getting loaded by that time of this $.watch, +1  for the idea :)

Comment: You could try and wrap the focus() call with a $timeout, so you make sure you're getting the focus after the next cycle. Not the most beautiful solution but it might work.

Comment: Thank you very much cheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeers :)